# SQL call keeps on returning error

Tags: php, mysql

The SQL call below keeps returning:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/content/76/10930776/html/apprentice/report.php on line 86

```
$sql = "select sum(".$column.") as totalmeetings,username from data where datediff(max(dateinput),min(dateinput)) <= ".$daysdifference." group by username ";
echo $sql;
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);



while($pcresult = $result->fetch_assoc())//line 86
    {

}
```

What am i doing wrong?
The SQL call prints out like this:

```
select sum(prospects1stmeeting) as totalmeetings,username from data where datediff(max(dateinput),min(dateinput)) <= 500 group by username
```

Comment: what you mean...all my other sql calls are working so not connection related

Comment: Fire that query directly in mysql engine and see what result/error you get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
select sum(prospects1stmeeting) as totalmeetings,username from data  
group by username 
having datediff(max(dateinput),min(dateinput)) <= 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at how you're trying to access the results:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($pcresult = $result_percentile->fetch_assoc())//line 86
{

}
```

$result and $results_percentile are not the same thing. You should try:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($pcresult = $result->fetch_assoc())//line 86
{

}
```

unless you're not showing your whole code.

**EDIT**

But since you edited your question to no longer reflect this answer, the answer is still that you're trying to access a non object. That means $result does not produce data that can be read as an associative array.

Comment: ok, so when you run this query in phpmyadmin or something what do you get?